# joomla Helix 2 Menu Issue multi language

Tags: joomla3.0

I have the following problem:

I have joomla 3.3.3 working with the HelixV2 framework in a multilanguage site. everything is working fine, except one thing:

there are two menus create in the same position:
[image]

here is the browser code for it:

```
  <div id="sp-menu" class="span5">
   <ul class="nav ">
    <li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/Terra_3/index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item-113"><a href="/Terra_3/index.php/about-us">About us </a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="sp-main-menu" class="visible-desktop">
    <ul class="sp-menu level-0"><li class="menu-item active first"><a href="http://localhost/Terra_3/" class="menu-item active first"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">Home</span></span></a></li>
      <li class="menu-item last"><a href="/Terra_3/index.php/about-us" class="menu-item last"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">About us </span></span></a></li></ul>        
   </div>               
  </div>
```

the part:

```
   <ul class="nav ">
    <li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/Terra_3/index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item-113"><a href="/Terra_3/index.php/about-us">About us </a></li>
   </ul>
```

should not be there!

anyone has an idea how to remove it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make "Main Menu" module unpublished

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward. You have assigned a "Menu Module" to the "Menu" position. By default Helix displays a menu which you can select in the template itself under the tab "Menu". So basically make your module unpublished and, if necessary, select the right menu in the template.

Which brings us to the multilingual support of Helix 2. Support which is in my opinion not so developer friendly as it should be. The template itself doesn't have a solution to support multiple languages which is mainly caused by the main menu selection. The template can only display one menu (i.e. one menu language). If you want to display more than 1 language the solution is to duplicate your template and assign the correct menu language to it (don't forget to assign the template to the right language). Developers will see the problem right away since making a change to the template would require it to be done several times (depending on how many languages you have).

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem, but for me works another solution: instead of copy something, I change the menu module positions to non-helix positions. Because of the Helix own menu management the navigations stays in the right place and are no double anymore. Maybe it works for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without copying the template:

*The following solution reads the current language tag and manual load the specific 'mainmenu-languageTag' menu into our menu location.*

### 1. Modify template menu.php

`templates/{YOUR TEMPLATE}/features/menu.php`

#### From

```
class Helix3FeatureMenu {

    private $helix3;

    public function __construct($helix3){
        $this->helix3 = $helix3;
        $this->position = 'menu';
    }

    public function renderFeature() {

        $menu_type = $this->helix3->getParam('menu_type');

        ob_start();

        if($menu_type == 'mega_offcanvas') { ?>
            <div class='sp-megamenu-wrapper'>
                <a id="offcanvas-toggler" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                <?php $this->helix3->loadMegaMenu('hidden-sm hidden-xs'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else if ($menu_type == 'mega') { ?>
            <div class='sp-megamenu-wrapper'>
                <a id="offcanvas-toggler" class="visible-sm visible-xs" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                <?php $this->helix3->loadMegaMenu('hidden-sm hidden-xs'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <a id="offcanvas-toggler" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        <?php }

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

#### To

```
class Helix3FeatureMenu {

    private $helix3;

    public function __construct($helix3){
        $this->helix3 = $helix3;
        $this->position = 'menu';
    }

    public function renderFeature() {

        $menu_type = $this->helix3->getParam('menu_type');

        $name = '';

        if (JLanguageMultilang::isEnabled())
        {
            $lang = JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();

            // Please replace to your multi-language menutype name
            $name = 'mainmenu-' . strtolower($lang);
        }

        ob_start();

        if($menu_type == 'mega_offcanvas') { ?>
            <div class='sp-megamenu-wrapper'>
                <a id="offcanvas-toggler" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                <?php $this->helix3->loadMegaMenu('hidden-sm hidden-xs', $name); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else if ($menu_type == 'mega') { ?>
            <div class='sp-megamenu-wrapper'>
                <a id="offcanvas-toggler" class="visible-sm visible-xs" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                <?php $this->helix3->loadMegaMenu('hidden-sm hidden-xs', $name); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <a id="offcanvas-toggler" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        <?php }

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

### 2. Create language specific menus

[image]

### 3. Preview

[image]